# Using ENV var to just specify database name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

I know that I can define DATABASE_URL for each virtualhost and that overwrites app's config/database.yaml file. But I dont want to duplicate host,password etc in each virtual hosts' file. So my plan is to specify hostname,username, password configuration once in general httpd.conf file and then configuring database name for each virtualhost.

Instead of using this for each vhost

```
SetEnv DATABASE_URL mysql://username:password@host/database
```

I want to do this for http.conf

```
SetEnv DATABASE_URL mysql://username:password@host
```

and this for each vhost

```
SetEnv DATABASE_NAME APP-SPECIFIC-DB-NAME
```

How can I achive that kind of DRY configuration? without modifying any of the apps' code.

Comment: Just misread your question a bit, so let's change the answer to a comment... Have you considered using environment variables that you can access with ruby code such as ENV['DBPASSWORD'] ?

Comment: I dont want to change any of the config/database.yaml files since there are tons of apps that are running. So I am trying to find a solution that is supported by default/fresh rails applications. Basically I dont want to modify apps to adopt my server configuration, instead I am trying to adopt my system to the default rails apps, like heroku does.(FYI, it modifies database.yaml file during push).